# Alternative way to evaluate $\int x^{-11} (1+x^4)^{-1/2} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

The question is to evaluate $$\int x^{-11} (1+x^4)^{-1/2} dx$$

My book gives the following solution

$$I=\int \frac{dx}{x^{13} (1+\frac{1}{x^4})^{1/2}}$$ If we substitute $(1+\frac{1}{x^4})=R^2$ then $\frac{-4}{x^5} dx=2RdR$ Now,$$I=\frac{dx}{x^{13}(1+\frac{1}{x^4})^{1/2}}=-1/2\int (R^2-1)^2 dR$$ which can be easily integrated.

However I am looking for alternative ways to evaluate this integral.Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

One long way is $x^2=\tan t$ then $dx=\dfrac{1+\tan^2t}{2\sqrt{\tan t}}dt$ and
$$I=\dfrac12\int \tan^{-6}t(1+\tan^2t)^\frac12dt=\dfrac12\int\dfrac{\cos^4t}{\sin^6t}\cos t\,dt$$
now let $\sin t=u$ so
$$I=\dfrac12\int\dfrac{1}{u^6}-\dfrac{2}{u^4}+\dfrac{1}{u^2}\,du$$